# Error argument is of length zero occurs when creating my own sorting function

Tags: r

```
*> csort <- function(c){
     i<-1
     for (i in 1:length(c)-1) {
         j <- i+1
         for (j in 2:length(c)) {
             if(c[i] >= c[j])c[c(i,j)] <- c[c(j,i)]
             j = j + 1
         }
         i = i + 1
     }
 }
> csort(a)
Error in if (c[i] >= c[j]) c[c(i, j)] <- c[c(j, i)] : 
argument is of length zero*
```

This is what RStudio do when I run it. I do not know what cause the zero here.

Comment: I've removed all the continuation "+" signs from your code so we can paste it into R easily so we can run it. Posting cut-and-pastable code is a good idea on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

your mistake is in this line

```
for (i in 1:length(c)-1)
```

and should be

```
for (i in 1:(length(c)-1))
```

since $:$ operator precedes $-$.

an example is

```
1:(5-1)
#[1] 1 2 3 4
1:5-1
#[1] 0 1 2 3 4
```

so error happen in index with Zero value.

```
csort <- function(d){

  for (i in 1:(length(d)-1)) {

     for (j in (i+1):length(d)) {
         if(d[i] >= d[j])d[c(i,j)] <- d[c(j,i)]

     }

  }
return(d)
}
d<-c(5:1,-1:3,-9,-3,10,9,-20,1,20,-6,5)
any((csort(d)==sort(d))==F)
#[1] FALSE
```

you can improve this function.

Comment: Oh, Jesus. Thank you. But after I done that it shows not to be a sort because the way I wrote it. I am still struggling .

Comment: you want to sort a vector?

Comment: Yes, I want to sort a vector in increasing order.

Comment: I made a function based in yours. see it in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
csort <- function(c){
  p <- 1
  povit <- c[1]
  c <- c[-1]
  left <- c()
  right <- c()
  left <- c[which(c <= povit)]
  right <- c[which(c > povit)]
  if(length(left) > 1){
  left <- csort(left)
  }
  if(length(right) > 1){
    right <- csort(right)
  }
  return(c(left ,povit,right))
}
```

I viewed more about sorting online and this is a pivot sort way.